# c# taskbar button switching/moving in multiple display environment

Tags: c#, winforms, taskbar

I've created a winforms application. All is running fine, also the taskbar button is created and shown in taskbar including the correct icon.

Whenever I move the form from one display to the second display, the taskbar button stays at the display from where the form was initial start.

I also compared the settings with another winforms application where the behaviour is correct. Means, the button is `moving/switching/whatever` to the active display where the form is moved to.

Hopefully it is just a small thing, but I came not across with it.

Comment: Try setting `ShowInTaskbar` to `false` and back to `true`

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Thanks, but this didn't helped. Also if I set `ShowInTaskbar` to `true`  after the `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: I meant doing so after the window has moved a screen, ye? Not in the designer

Comment: That do the trick, but is not a solution. It results in flickering the form. Thats more a kind of workaround

Comment: The `ShowInTaskbar` wraps around move than a few flags and calls, I believe. You could dig in to what messages are needed to just refresh the taskbar item, and maybe then the flickering won't occur.

Comment: Hi @RezaAghaei I will let you and all the others know if I found a solution. Currently I'm not able to solve my problem. Your answer isn't usefull for my problem because the answer isn't related to it. Sorry for that ;)

Comment: @Pew Thank you for your feedback, so please share your logic to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RezaAghaei The problem is related to the used framework to style the forms and controls. This questions is answered to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an OS feature.

- For windows 7 there is no built-in support to show taskbar for your second monitor and your taskbar buttons will always show on first monitor taskbar.
- For windows 8 you can open `Taskbar` properties and in `Multiple displays` settings, check `Show taskbar on all displays` and then set the value of `Show taskbar bottons on:` to `Taskbar where window is open`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that I'm using W10 and W8.1 as OS. I know about this feature

Comment: The same setting will apply in windows 8.1. So what is the problem?